# Spree-editor gives the error in production while uploading image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am using Spree-editor and  in that I am using the ckeditor while Uploading Image On development everything  working fine image is  uploading but on production the Image Upload gives error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/ckeditor_assets/pictures/4/thumb_404-dog.png")
```

I also done this but not worked.

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to add assets to `precompile` array.

Consider adding next line inside your `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/*)
```

Comment: You should run `rake assets:precompile` after that, I think

Comment: I am deploying the code through capistrano that do that thing by default

Comment: Did you try to run in in production mode locally?

Comment: After doing so much googling i found this config.public_file_server.enabled = true and it worked..